# Requested resource not available error

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, mapping

i am facing a problem with URL mapping with Spring.
the first method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/indexActel1")
    public String Affichage(Model model)
    {   
         model.addAttribute("listeOds",serviceOds.getAll());
        model.addAttribute("listeParam",serviceParam. getAll());
         model.addAttribute("listeDim",serviceDim.getAll());
         return "Actel1/Affichage11";
    }
```

works when i use the url: indexActel1.htm (*.htm is the url-pattern that i declared in my web-xml).

but i am facing a problem with another method in the same class, i am getting the error: **The requested resource is not available.**!
even that i am using the same url-pattern and the same address i declre in the request Mapping annotation.

this is the method i mapped, and that i want to call.
it is a method in the same class as the first one.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateParamActel1" )
    public String UpdateParam(Model model,@RequestParam String id)
    {   
        identifiant=id;
        System.out.println("id parametre ="+ id+" longueur: "+id.length());
        System.out.println("id manuel ="+ "105"+" longueur: "+"105".length());
        Ods_Gis_Actel Obj= serviceOds.getById(id);
        Toupdate=serviceParam.getById(id);;
        System.out.println("id ="+ id);
        System.out.println("step 1 ! \n");
        model.addAttribute("label",Obj.getNom_actel());
        System.out.println("step 2 ! \n");
        System.out.println("code: "+Obj.getCode_actel()); 
        System.out.println("step 3 ! \n");
        return "Actel1/rechercheDimDes11";
    }
```

what can be the problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: there is no exception, it is just a 404 error: the requsted method not found,i can't see an exception in the console.

Comment: Really strange, how one method can be called while another method can't! is there sth like a "connexion" to the controller that is closed when one method is executed??

Comment: What do you see in the standard output? Are your log statements being written? What happens when you debug and set a breakpoint in the second method? WHat's the URLs being used to invoke both methods?

Comment: well well, it was just a '/' that spoiled my morning, thanks JB NIZET.(merci bien)